# Работа с DOM с помощью расширения

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь сделать расширение (первый раз работаю с расширениями), которое сможет отслеживать что ввел пользователь в input на странице сайта, как получить доступ через расширение к элементам на сайте?

Comment: Как я помню нужно использовать background-скрипты, подключаете их в манифесте и сможете обращатся к элементам в DOM дереве (в background скриптах).

Comment: рекомендую начинать с userscript https://www.tampermonkey.net/
Это проще чем  расширение делать